# ecb defining custom layout

Tags: cedet, emacs-ecb

I want to construct a ecb layout that has two special buffers. one is the output
of semantic-symref-symbol and the other is semantic-ia-fast-jump. How do I do this ?

I have cedet working and I have the ecb from Alex Ott's git repository.

The suggestions from here:
[How to remove directory window and add a cscope window in Emacs ECB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190062/how-to-remove-directory-window-and-add-a-cscope-window-in-emacs-ecb)
provide some input, but doesn't talk about how to hook up a function.

Comment: I wanted to mention that I did not know of ECB and am now exploring it as well. Thank you.